# Swift - Parse Facebook Login Immediately Defaults to User Cancelled Login

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I am just trying to check to make sure that my Parse and Facebook SDK setup are correct for a Facebook Sign Up and Login, but I run into an issue during my test where I set the Parse sign up function in my view did load, which when building apps in the past has brought me to a verify Facebook credentials page, but I get the line printed to my console where the user has cancelled, but I'm not sure why this would be happening.

Line that is printed = `"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login."`

AppDelegate.swift:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
// 
//
//  Created by on 3/10/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 . All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        Parse.setApplicationId("xxxxx", clientKey:"xxxxx")
            PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()


        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        FBAppCall.handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession(PFFacebookUtils.session())
    }


    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL,
        sourceApplication: String?,
        annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
            return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication,
                withSession:PFFacebookUtils.session())
    }



}
```

LoginViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        var permissions = ["public_profile","email","user_friends"]

        PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
            (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if let user = user {
                if user.isNew {
                    println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                } else {
                    println("User logged in through Facebook!")
                }
            } else {
                println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
            }
        })


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: AnyObject) {




    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work if you set up the frameworks correctly and follow the steps of Parse's Facebook setup guide (https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users). The two main differences I'm noticing between this and your code is the syntax for the PFFacebookUtils Login function in your view controller and the func application at the very end of your app delegate is put before the func applicationWillTerminate in mine.

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Parse

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    //X's replace my actual Parse information

    Parse.setApplicationId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", clientKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

/*
func application(application: UIApplication, url: NSURL, sourceApplication: NSString, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
        application,
        openURL: url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication as String,
        annotation: annotation)

}*/

func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

let permissions = [ "email","user_birthday", "public_profile", "user_friends"]

@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    }
}

}
```

The @IBAction is for a simple UIButton I put in the center of the blank viewcontroller in my Main.storyboard

Objective-C Bridging Header:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

Hope this solves your problem!